# How to perform Camel routes with different exchanges synchronously?

Tags: apache-camel, synchronous

I have some synchronous Camel routes with:

```
from("file:...")
...
.to("direct:next1")

from("direct:next1")
...
```

Now I'd like to run another route with a different exchange synchronously:

```
from("file:local/A")
...
.to("file:remote/A")
.to("direct:next2")

from("file:remote/A")  // direct:next2 ?
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To be clear:  you want to run the file route after you want to run the `direct` route?

Comment: @Makoto I want to run two file routes sychronously (`next2`) with two different files.

Comment: Okay.  Given that you're reading two different files I would anticipate that you're going to be doing this *a*synchronously, though.  Can you drum up a slightly more concrete example?

Comment: @Makoto I want to run them _synchronously_ since the file of the scond route `remote/A` doesn't exist unless the first route `local/A` has been completed. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - the elephant in the room.  Both of your `file` routes are going to start and run asynchronously by default because there is no dependency between those two routes at an EIP level to tell one to fire after the other.

There are two ways to solve this (e.g. to force an interdependency between the routes):

- Require `local/A` to start the `remote/A` route (and to not attempt to *re*start the route if it's running.
- Allow `remote/A` to poll for the file at given intervals.

---

Chain-starting the routes is a more sophisticated function of Camel and it allows you to precisely define the lifecycle of routes at your leisure.  In this case, after your `local/A` file route finishes consuming, it would start up the `remote/A` route.

For that we can leverage the [Control Bus EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/controlbus-component.adoc) which allows us to control the lifecycle of routes directly.

```
from("file:local/A")
        .routeId("localA")
        .process(aProcessor)
        .to("controlbus:route?routeId=remoteA&action=start");

from("file:remote/A")
        .routeId("remoteA")
        .autoStartup(false)
        .process(aDifferentProcessor)
        .to("controlbus:route?routeId=remoteA&action=suspend&async=true");
```

---

Polling is probably the most straightforward approach and it doesn't require much in the way of finickiness.  Either the file exists or it doesn't when you go to process it, and you can choose to wait for a specific period of time when that file appears again.

```
from("file:local/A")
        .routeId("localA")
        .process(aProcessor);


from("file:remote/A?delay=2m")
        .routeId("remoteA")
        .process(aDifferentProcessor);
}
```

My *preference* would be to poll at a fixed interval or on a cron schedule, simply because it doesn't feel like you'd be gaining true synchronicity with either approach.  You get the power to decide what fires when, but it's not 100% synchronous like `direct` routes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Control Bus looks good. But how is `file:local/A` routed to `file:remote/A` (see the two consecutive `to()`s in my updated question)?

Comment: That should be okay.  A `to` file route is a producer and it will be presumed that it's going to write a file in the `local/A` directory for later consumption.

Comment: Why "_write a file in the local/A directory_"? `local/A` is already there (that's why I put it in `from`) and it should be _read_ and transferred to `remote/A`. After this transfer is complete the next route should run.

Comment: @GeroldBroser:  The `file` route is a producer and it will write a file to that specific directory - that's how the component works.  I think I may have misspoken and meant `remote/A`.